# pass Intent from BroadcastReceiver to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have retrieved call log data(number,type,date,duration) in broadcast Receiver class.Now I want to set that data into list view of activity class.I can't get how to send data through intent between these two activities and set into list view.

code to call in activity class:

```
String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")); // check for null
                        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")); // convert to date its long
                        String message_text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")); // check type and get names

                        // send email from here
                        sendSMSEmail(number, date, message_text, type);
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
                String finalData=number+"\n"+date+"\n"+message_text+"\n"+type;
```

Also I pass the Intent

```
Intent i=new Intent();
        i.putExtra(number,number);
        i.putExtra(date, date);
        i.putExtra(message_text, message_text);
        i.putExtra(type,type);
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: did you call new activity in `BroadcastReciver`?

Comment: put some of your sample working code

Comment: no,I have no idea to call new activity in broadcastReceiver class.I am new in android ,so can u please help me out to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do your job with 2 way,first define your adapter with `static public` and in `BroadcastReciver` after setting data into list call `context.adapter.notifyDataSetChange();` and dont need to pass data from intent to your class

and second way that you can go is write one receiver in the class that you want update your list and in `BroadcastReciver` send another `Broadcast` to that. and in receiver update your list.

I hope so that is useful for you

Comment: sir,I have to send that retrieved data into Activity class from Broadcast receiver class and set into list view present in activity classprotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);